# BufferedReader won't read

Tags: java, file, oop, bufferedreader

I have a program that the username and password are in a text file and the text file looks like this:

```
election:12345
```

and I have this code to read the file

```
try {
    BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("election_un_pass.txt"));
    String line="";

    while((line=read.readLine())!=null) {
        String [] info=line.split(":");

        if(info[0].matches(Login.uname) && info[1].matches(Login.pass)){
            new Main();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or Password might not be correct");
        }
        Login.txtUName.setText("");
        Login.txtPassword.setText("");
     }
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Every time I run my program, even tho the username and password that I entered are correct, the `Username or Password might not be correct` message will still appear and `new Main()` won't appear.

Comment: Please check the Login.uname and Login.pass values it seems they are not matching.

Comment: Sure that you don't want to use `String.equals`? And what are the values of `Login`?

Comment: @VuralAcar oh they are actually matched and the Login.uname and Login.pass are initialized to the txtUName.getText() and txtPassword.getText() but because of your suggestion i just directly used the txtUName.getText() and txtPassword.getText(). thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Marvin  `txtUName.getText()` and `txtPassword.getText()` but i just directly used them now and it's now fixed thank you so much!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

1. Learn how to debug in whatever IDE you are using. With debug mode you can execute the code one line at a time and see the values of the variables at each point.
2. Increase the logging information when the error occurrs

For example you could print to the console/logs/dialog:

```
String msg = String.format("could not find user name: [%s] and password: [%s] in line: [%s]", Login.uname, Login.pass, line);
```

Obviously you shouldn't print the expected user name and password anywhere when an incorrect value is input for security reasons, but it might be a quick way to find out whats going wrong :) It could be as simple as trailing whitespace characters somewhere or incorrect case somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you want to use `String.matches(regex)` for your comparisons? The argument is taken as a regular expression, so any regex meta-characters in your `Login.uname` or `Login.pass` values would be interpreted as regex. This means your match might work in ways you don't expect.

I suspect you really want to say:

```
if (info[0].equals(Login.uname) && info[1].equals(Login.pass)) {
```

instead.